# Bind list to DataGridView

Tags: c#, list, datagridview, bind

I have a list from a class and I want to show it in a datagridview.

This is my code but it doesn't show the list:

```
public partial class Configuration : UserControl
{
    TestInfoClass liste = new TestInfoClass();

    public Configuration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        datagridview_Items.DataSource = liste;    // here not work, not show anything        
    }
}
```

main form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   Configuration list_to_dgv = new Configuration();
   TestInfoClass testInfo = null;
   //code...
   Configuration list_to_dgv = new Configuration();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your returns function is?So i make an example here by myself .
The function that returns your list should be something like this :

```
 public DataSet ShowUsers()
    {
        DataSet op = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection objconnection = new SqlConnection(obj.strconnection());
        SqlCommand objcommand = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet objdataset = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter objdataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand = objcommand;
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection;
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "ShowUsers";
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, "sheet");
        return objdataset;
    }
```

And in your form you should have some thing like this :

```
 DGVShowLetter.DataSource = obj.ShowUsers();
 DGVShowLetter.DataMember = "sheet";
```

So i think you should add a **DataMember** and because of that it doesn't work .

If you have a list of objects in your class you should convert the list to a table like this :

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
        list.Add(new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "Row 2", "Row 2" });
        list.Add(new string[] { "Row 3" });

        // Convert to DataTable.
        DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

The convert function :

```
static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string[]> list)
    {
        // New table.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        // Get max columns.
        int columns = 0;
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
        if (array.Length > columns)
        {
            columns = array.Length;
        }
        }

        // Add columns.
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
        table.Columns.Add();
        }

        // Add rows.
        foreach (var array in list)
        {
        table.Rows.Add(array);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Is it c# application ?or web form application?

Comment: my list is fill into a class, not in a funtcion

Comment: i tried that you say, but my list contains, string, byte, bool... it´s not always the same parameters, thank you

Comment: So you can pass your list to the function ,instead using List<string[]> list use your own list :List<yourownlist> list